# How to execute "bin/setup" in rails on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

As far as I know `bin/setup` is for easy set up for every project in rails e.g installing required gems, preparing database etc. But how to do this in Windows environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need ruby installed first. 
Open a command prompt in the relevant folder and run: 
`ruby bin/setup`